# Flask app on ECS that pull images from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-codepipeline

I have a flask app that I want to pull images to display from an s3 bucket.

How do I implement the credentials parts? what I mean is:

Do I use boto3 with aws credentials to pull the images from the bucket?

Can I use boto3 without the aws credentials and attach a role to the ECS? so it can pull the images without credentials?

At the moment what I want to achieve is to put the app in the CodePipeline to ECS and I want to update the images to the s3 bucket, so the flask app on ECS display the new images on s3 bucket.

I am confused as to what is a best practice for credentials etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always use IAM Roles** and never use any explicit access/secret keys in production. Read more about [**EC2 instance roles** here](https://aws.nz/best-practice/ec2-instance-roles/), the same applies to *ECS IAM Roles*.

In your ECS case you should:

1. **Create IAM Role** with permissions to `s3:GetObject` from the S3 bucket.
2. **Attach** that IAM Role to your ECS Task as a **`TaskRole`**.
3. If you are using ECS Fargate instead of EC2-based ECS you will also need an **`ExecutionRole`** that essentially gives Fargate the permissions to launch your task.

In **CloudFormation template** it would be something like this:

```
Parameters:
  S3BucketName:
    Type: String

Resources:
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
      Cpu: ...
      Memory: ...
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - ...


  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com ]
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: TaskAccess
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Action:
            - s3:GetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
            - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${S3BucketName}/*"

  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com ]
          Action: 
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
```

---

However there is often no point *downloading* **public images** from S3 to your Flask web app. Instead make the images *public* in S3 and refer directly to them from your HTML with `<img src="https://your-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/whatever/image.jpg"/>`.

If the images are *not public* you still shouldn't download them to Flask and instead create [**pre-signed URLs**](https://aws.nz/best-practice/s3-presigned-url/) that provide time-limited access to the files in S3. Again linking directly to the S3 location without downloading the files from S3 to Flask first.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, this is gold! Thank you very much for your time. Unfortunately I didn't go with that approach as the HTML code is complicated and assosiated with a jupyter notebook and it would be lot of trouble, I ended up pushing the new images I want to server in codecommit and from there to the pipeline